# Convert from JSON with Jackson Annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, playframework-2.4

I am attempting to convert JSON into a Java object with the Play framework.  I do not have easy control over the input JSON, which contains dashes in the names.

```
{ "field-name": "value" }
```

As a result, I cannot create a Java object with a default mapping to the JSON.  I have a class which looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Data {
  @JsonProperty("field-name")
  public String fieldName;
}
```

I know that [Play 2.4 uses Jackson](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJsonActions), and
I have a unit test which is able to populate the object from the JSON using a default Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

The JSON is the body of a POST request, and I attempt to use it like this:

```
    Form<Data> form = Form.form(Data.class).bindFromRequest();
```

If I print `form`, I can that the data field is populated with the expected values.  However, when I do `form.get()`, the returned value has a null field.  (In the actual code, there are more fields, which are Strings or longs.  All of them are null or 0.)

Am I attempting to customize the JSON deserialization in the wrong way?  Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've expected you've used the wrong way to deserialize. The Forms class is for PlayForms only and not for Json request. Have a look at the [BodyParser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaBodyParsers) and [JsonActions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJsonActions) documentation:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result index() {
   RequestBody body = request().body();
   Data data = Json.fromJson(body.asJson(), Data.class);
   return ok("Got java object: " + data.toString());
}
```